# Halo around button & checkbutton

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I got halo around checkbutton radiobutton & menu labels...

How can i remove this halo? (as you can see there is bright bound around button)

[image: Picture]

I'm using below setting and wondering if i miss something

```
set default_font {lucida -12 normal }
option add *font $default_font
option add *background #D4D0C8
option add *foreground #000000
option add *activeBackground #ececec
option add *activeForeground #100
option add *selectBackground #c3c3c3
option add *disableForeground #a3a3a3
option add *troughColor #c3c3c3
option add *highlightBackground #d9d9d9
option add *width 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure as checkbuttons render differently on my system (different OS) but that ring will be either the border or the highlight ring. The border can be removed by setting its width to zero by configuring the `-borderwidth` option. The highlight (a.k.a. focus) ring can be removed by setting its width to zero by configuring the `-highlightthickness` option.

They correspond to the `borderWidth` and `highlightThickness` option properties, respectively.